# app with touch recognize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, touch

i want to build an app that there is a menu in the app(the menu will be picture i will build) and in the image will be couple of items.

and if the user will click on one of the items in the menu the app will go to a method i will build.

how can i do it?

Comment: First: Your question is pretty vague, StackOverflow is rather a place for specific questions. Also, you might want to accept some answers or you are unlikely to receive any help at all.

Comment: Is it me or has the last month seem to have had a rash of "Write my app for me" questions? Many of these have to be listed in SO already. Don't want to discourage new users but this is getting out of hand.

Comment: @Phlibbo: Unfortunately, there is always a supply of willing necks for the Help Vampire. See below. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, just use IB and first add UIImageView and fill it with the background image of your menu. Then add some UIButtons on top of that UIImageView. Then connect those buttons through the connections tab in IB to the methods in your code...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can make the button "borderless" to make it invisible to the user. At least you can on IB when making mac apps. Give it a look :)

Comment: No problem, you can make a custom button, it can be invisible, just don't add a background to it... But you should think of giving a user feedback that the button was pressed.

Comment: it's called a custom button. They are invisible if you put neither text nor images in this button.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UIButton and IBActions or do this by touching inside of the image frame of your menu item:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    if ([touch view] == MenuItem1) { (the method you're going to use) }

}
```